# Python string format find the requested variable

Tags: python

Is there anything ready on the `str` to get the the list of values requested in the string?

For example if I have a string like: `I need two values {foo} and {boo}"`, is there anything that return me a list like `('foo', 'boo')` or I must write a regex?

I see there is the `Template` class in string and the class has a `flags` method, but I don't understand how to use it.

Thank you

Comment: your question is not clear. do you want to get string which are surrounded by curly braces? if yes, regular expression is the best thing. or, you want to search for a set of words in a string?

Comment: @Rawing thanks for the answer. This is exactly what I needed!